# I am getting this error while am trying to bring data from cloud firestore to my flutter app

Tags: flutter, firebase

ERROR - >

Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///data/user/0/com.example.hangout/cache/scaled_8213e05d-3981-48c7-ac51-d57a3ab4b8f04882445254643686983.jpg

here is the code for the dashboard screen

[dashboardScreen.dart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmOY8.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are storing the images without the full URL and trying to display it without concatenating it with the base url.

You have to options:

- Concatenate the image path with the base URL in the `NetworkImage`.
- Store the full pathof the image in the Firestore.

Comment: how can i Concatenate the image path with the base URL in the NetworkImage.

Comment: Can you please provide me by the source of the image? where it come from? and how do you upload it?

Comment: i uploaded it via my mobile camera, it's like a signup page where the user has to upload a profile image, it's the profile image

Comment: try this, Image.network(snapshot.data!.docs[index]['profileurl']), can you show the program fo uploading image

Comment: @TasinMahamud Have you actually uploaded the file to Firebase Storage or any server or you have just stored the file path returned from the picker?